# Get all relations to members in a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have three models (models changed, I wouldn't use a has_many :through for this kind of relationship normally):

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :image_users
    has_many :images, through: :image_users
end
class ImageUser << ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :image
end

class Image << ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :image_users
    has_many :users, through: :image_users
    has_many :comments, through: :image_comments
end

class ImageComment << ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :image
    belongs_to :comment
end


class Comment << ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :image_comments
    has_many :images, through: :image_comments
end
```

Given a user, how do I select all comments on their images? Ideally I'd do this with ActiveRecord or SQL to avoid loading lots of objects into memory. Hopefully this hasn't been asked before, it was pretty difficult to google for.

Comment: don't you think you're doing it wrong?

Comment: This is for a content-feed type of system (aka "recent comments on your images"). Some model names have been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this and let Rails handle the SQL:

```
@user.images.includes(:comments).map(&:comments)
```

Comment: I'll select this as the answer because it does work, although I'll advise anybody finding this via Google that this gets you an array of ActiveRecord::Collection objects, which you have to merge together.

Comment: True! You can just throw a `flatten` on the end and get an array of all comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
User
has_many :images
has_many :comments

Image
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments

Comment
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :image
```

and it's gonna be something like this

```
@user.images.each {|e| e.comments}
```

Comment: This does work, but it has an N+1 query problem. Also, you want ````.map```` instead of ````.each```` Can you do this without the N+1?

Answer (score 1):

If you take the relationships from @railsr's answer, you can do it like this:

```
Comment.where(image_id: @user.images.pluck(:id))
```

Granted, this takes two queries, but you could use some raw SQL and make it into one.

Comment: Perhaps comment was a bad fake table name to use—comments and images would be related with a has_many :through relationship, so this doesn't work.